Does a strictly incresing cumulative distribution function in $[0,1]$ always admit a density?
Consider some strictly increasing cdf $G(x):[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$.
I know $G$ is almost everywhere differentiable since $G$ is monotonic.
Moreover, I know $G(x)$ admits a density if and only if it is absolutely continuous with respect to the lebesgue measure.
Since $G$ is continuous and strictly increasing, it is absolutely continuous if and only if the image $G(A)$ of the set $A:=\{x\in[0,1]: G'(x)=\infty\}$ is of measure 0.
(Continuous strictly increasing function is absolutely continuous iff set of infinite derivative maps to measure zero set)
Therefore, the existence of density function of $G$ pins down to determining whether
$G(A)$ is of Lebesgue measure 0.
I have 2 questions.

Is $A$ Lebesgue measure 0?
Is $G(A)$ Lebesgue measure 0?

I believe (though not have proven yet) $1$ is true because $G$ has bounded codomain.
I have no idea about 2.
Any suggestions / intuititons / similar results or counterexamples would be greatly helpful.

There is a well known construction of  a strictly increasing continuous singular distribution function. You can get it from Wikipedia or the book by Hewitt and Stromberg.

Of course not. For each $r=p/q$ rational number of $(0,1)$ with $p$ and $q$ relatively prime consider the number $w_r=1/q^4$, $s=\sum _rw_r$ and the probability $p_r=w_r/s$. It has a CDF strictly increasing with no density.
